# Managing Chat History with Socket.io/React/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am working on a real time chat feature in my application using [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). I have the sockets set up, and users are able to send messages to each other.

I defined the following helper functions to assist in setting up a socket, and retrieving the chat history from the server:

```js
export const initiateChatSocket = (room, username) => {
  socket = io("http://localhost:5000/chat", {
    transports: ["websocket"],
  });
  console.log(`Connecting socket...`);
  if (socket && room) socket.emit("join", room, username);
};

export const loadInitialChat = (cb) => {
  if (!socket) return true;

  socket.on("joinResponse", (msg) => cb(null, msg));
};

export const subscribeToChat = (cb) => {
  if (!socket) return true;
  socket.on("chat", (msg) => {
    console.log("Websocket event received!");
    return cb(null, msg);
  });
};

export const sendMessage = (room, message) => {
  if (socket) socket.emit("chat", { message, room });
};
```

Adapted from [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-socketio-rooms-with-react-hooks-4723dd44692e) guide.

Here is the backend code:

```js
chatNsp.on("connection", (socket) => {
  let socketRoom;
  socket.on("join", (roomID, userID) => {
    socket.join(roomID);
    socketRoom = roomID;
    socket.emit("joinResponse", socketHistory[socketRoom]);
  });

  socket.on("chat", (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(socketRoom).emit("chat", data.message);
    socketHistory[socketRoom] = socketHistory[socketRoom]
      ? [data.message, ...socketHistory[socketRoom]]
      : [data.message];
  });
});
```

When a user connects, they can successfully receive the chat history for the room. That is being stored in the `socketHistory` object:

```js
socketHistory {
  '0b1b05e2-1c50-42b3-baab-59b5548c6930': [ 'Test', 'Baz', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Foo' ]
}
```

There is a disconnect between the two components that use the chat component, `LiveStream` and `ViewStream`. The chat in the `LiveStream` component gets overwritten with each new message. However the `ViewStream` component maintains the full history as expected. The full history is still available on the server. In my chat component, I am adding the message to my `chat` array in state before sending the message, but I can't seem to track down the problem.

```js
const Chat = ({ username, roomId, socket }) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadInitialChat((err, data) => {
      if (err) return;

      if (data !== null) {
        setChat(data);
      }
    });
  }, [roomId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToChat((err, data) => {
      if (err) return;
      
      setChat([...chat, data]);
    });
  }, [chat]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    sendMessage(roomId, message);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        placeholder="Send a Message"
        value={message}
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></TextField>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setChat([...chat, message]);
          sendMessage(roomId, message);
          setMessage("");
        }}
      >
        Send
      </Button>
      {chat ? chat.map((m, i) => <p key={i}>{m}</p>) : ""}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my `LiveStream` component:

```js
...removed for brevity

const LiveStream = ({ username, roomId, peer, peerId }) => {
  // Set the user's video stream in state once given permission on component load
  const [videoStream, _setVideoStream] = useState(null);
  const [socketRegistered, setSocketRegistered] = useState(false);
  const videoStreamRef = useRef(videoStream);
  const setVideoStream = (data) => {
    videoStreamRef.current = data;
    _setVideoStream(data);
  };
  const chatSocket = initiateChatSocket(roomId, username);

  useEffect(() => {
    videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
    viewerVideoGrid = document.getElementById("viewer-grid");
    const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
    const configOptions = { video: true, audio: false };
    myVideo.muted = true;
    async function enableStream() {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(configOptions);
        setVideoStream(stream);
        setupMediaRecorder(stream);
        addVideoStream(videoSocket, chatSocket, myVideo, stream);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }

    if (!videoStream) {
      enableStream();
    } else {
      return function cleanup() {
        videoStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.stop();
        });
        disconnectSocket();
      };
    }
  }, [videoStream]);

  useEffect(() => {
    videoSocket = initiateVideoSocket(roomId, username, peerId);

    console.log(videoSocket);
    // When a viewer connects, this event is emitted and the streamer will connect to the viewer.
    videoSocket.on("viewer-connected", (id, viewer, viewerPeerId) => {
      console.log("inside videoSocket listener", videoStream);
      connectToNewViewer(viewerPeerId, videoStream);
    });
  }, [videoStream]);

   ...removed for brevity

  // Function to connect to new viewer using PeerJS. Inputs are the peerID of the viewer, and the streamer's video stream to send
  // to the viewer.
  function connectToNewViewer(viewerId, stream) {
    const call = peer.call(viewerId, stream);
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
      addViewerStream(video, userVideoStream);
    });
    call.on("close", () => {
      video.remove();
    });

    peers[viewerId] = call;
  }

  // Function to add the streamer's video to the LiveStream component on load. Called after permission is given to access the
  // camera and mic.
  function addVideoStream(vs, cs, video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      video.play();
    });
    videoGrid.append(video);
  }

  function addViewerStream(vs, cs, video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
      video.play();
    });
    viewerVideoGrid.append(video);
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Grid container direction="column" justify="space-between" spacing={10}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={8} sm={6}>
            <div id="video-grid"></div>
            <StreamControls
              mediaRecorder={mediaRecorder}
              stoppedVideo={stoppedVideo}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4}>
            <Chat username={username} roomId={roomId} socket={chatSocket} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <div id="viewer-grid"></div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
...removed for brevity
);
```

And here is `ViewStream`:

```js
...removed for brevity

const ViewStream = ({ peer, streamerPeerId, ...props }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const room = props.match.params.id;
  const viewerPeer = peer;
  const viewerVideoSocket = initiateVideoSocket(
    room,
    props.username,
    props.viewerPeerId
  );

  const viewerChatSocket = initiateChatSocket(room, props.username);
  let streamerVideoDiv;

  useEffect(() => {
    viewerVideoSocket.emit("viewer-connected", room, props.username, peer.id);

    viewerPeer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer();
      call.on("stream", (stream) => {
        streamerVideoDiv = document.getElementById("streamer-video");
        const content = document.createElement("video");
        content.srcObject = stream;
        content.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
          content.play();
        });
        streamerVideoDiv.append(content);
      });
    });

    return () => {
      disconnectSocket();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container direction="column" justify="space-between" spacing={10}>
        <Grid item xs={8} sm={6}>
          <div id="streamer-video"></div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={4}>
          <Chat
            username={props.username}
            roomId={props.match.params.id}
            socket={viewerChatSocket}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the setState, inside the useEffect in chat.js. You can use the existing data in a callback function like this `setChat((existingData) => [...existingData, data]`. This means you can get rid of `chat` in the dependencies array, which means it only runs once. Maybe when that is cleared up, the issue will be more obvious.

Comment: Add to that ^ your LiveStream is getting the `roomId` as a prop where `ViewStream` is getting `roomId` from a route param, so it's probably re-initializing chat because it's being rerendered. You should try to limit when that chat socket is initiated to only the first render of each component, to ensure it doesn't change.

Comment: @xdumaine that's a good point. I hadn't thought about how `roomId` was being passed to each. I tried using the `useCallback` hook to prevent the `Chat` component from re-rendering, since the props shouldn't be changing. I also tried what @JakeAve suggested and rewrote my `setChat`, and took `chat` out of the dependency array. What else could I try to prevent the Chat component from re-rendering?